# Label points on individuals factor map (PCA) using FactoMineR

Tags: r, pca, labeling

I am running PCA using FactoMineR and cannot seem to get the individual points labeled on the Individuals factor map. My dataset ("ExData.csv") contains values in a matrix with 13 rows (labeled A through M) and 10 columns (labeled N through W).  I am running the following:

```
mydata <- read.csv("ExData.csv",header=TRUE,row.names=1)
attach(mydata)

library(FactoMineR)
X <- cbind(N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W)
res.pca <- PCA(X)
```

When PCA runs, I get the Individuals factor map (PCA) with the points labeled 1-13, instead of A trough M. The Variables factor map (PCA) properly labels the loadings N through W.

How can I get the individual points on the Individuals factor map (PCA) plot to be properly labeled (i.e., A through J)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question does not seem to have any statistical content, it is solely about how to achieve something with a specific programming language. As such, I vote to move it to StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your matrix `X` has column names but no row names. So the column labels appear in your PCA plot, but instead of row names you just get row *indices* as identification of the observations in the plot.

Here's an example:

```
#install.packages("FactoMineR")
library(FactoMineR)
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(matrix(runif(13 * 10),
                        nrow = 13,
                        ncol = 10,
                        dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:13], LETTERS[14:23])))

attach(df)
X <- cbind(N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W)
```

At this point `rownames(X)` is `NULL` and `PCA(X)` can only use the row indices to identify the observation in its plots.

To fix this, simply add the row names to the matrix `X` that is passed to `PCA()`:

```
# restore row names
rownames(X) <- rownames(df)   # or something similar in your actual program
res.pca <- PCA(X)
```

The result looks like this:

[image]
[image]